# Mikrotik route syntax to create a new routing table

Tags: mikrotik, iproute2

I want to replace my linux gateway box to Mikrotik. But I never found how to write this linux's iproute2 command in mikrotik's way:

```
ip route add default via 10.1.1.1 table browser
ip route add 10.1.2.0/24 via 10.1.1.2 table browser
ip rule add prio 100 from 10.1.6.2 lookup browser
```

anyone could lead me how to create a new routing table instead using the main's route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
/ip route
add gateway=10.1.1.1 routing-mark=browser
/ip route
add gateway=10.1.1.2 dst-address=10.1.2.0/24 routing-mark=browser
/ip route rule
add src-address=10.1.6.2 action=lookup table=browser
```

Note that in RouterOS, the priority is set by the order of the routing rules.